# Как вывести все новости из 4 разделов Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Всем привет. Есть кастомный компонент.. проблема в том что мне нужно из 4 категорий вывести все новости в один блок на сайте, но выводится только один из 4 айдишников. Как вывести всё сразу? Я думаю проблема не сложная.. просто я вообще не знаю php... помогите плиз. В кастомном компоненте такие файлы

component.php

```
    <?php if (!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED !== true) die();
    if (CModule::IncludeModule("iblock")) {
        $arSelect = array(
            "ID",
            "IBLOCK_ID",
            "PROPERTY_ATTR_SHORT_TITLE",
            "PROPERTY_ATTR_MEMBER_RUS",
            "PROPERTY_ATTR_MEMBER_DE",
            "DETAIL_PAGE_URL"
        );

        $arFilter = array(
            "IBLOCK_ID" => array(2,3,15,16),
            "ACTIVITY" => "Y",
            "!PROPERTY_ATTR_SHORT_TITLE" => false,
            array(
                "LOGIC" => "OR",
                array("!PROPERTY_ATTR_MEMBER_RUS" => false),
                array("!PROPERTY_ATTR_MEMBER_DE" => false)
            )
        );

        $arOrder = array(
            "PROPERTY_ATTR_SHORT_TITLE" => "ASC",
        );

        $res = CIBlockElement::GetList($arOrder, $arFilter, false, array("nPageSize" => 10, "bShowAll" => false), $arSelect);

        while ($ob = $res->GetNextElement()) {
            $arFields = $ob->GetFields();

    //        if (!empty($arFields["PROPERTY_ATTR_MEMBER_RUS_VALUE"]) || (!empty($arFields["PROPERTY_ATTR_MEMBER_DE_VALUE"]))) {

            // Формируем массив немецких партнеров
            foreach ($arFields["PROPERTY_ATTR_MEMBER_DE_VALUE"] as &$deMember) {
                $deMemberRes = CIBlockElement::GetByID($deMember);
                while ($de = $deMemberRes->GetNextElement())
                    $deMember = $de->GetFields();

                $deMember["DETAIL_PICTURE"] = CFile::GetPath($deMember["DETAIL_PICTURE"]);
            }

            // Формируем массив российских партнеров
            foreach ($arFields["PROPERTY_ATTR_MEMBER_RUS_VALUE"] as &$deMember) {
                $deMemberRes = CIBlockElement::GetByID($deMember);
                while ($de = $deMemberRes->GetNextElement())
                    $deMember = $de->GetFields();

                $deMember["DETAIL_PICTURE"] = CFile::GetPath($deMember["DETAIL_PICTURE"]);
            }

            $arResult["ITEMS"][] = $arFields;

            $arResult["NAV_STRING"] = $res->GetPageNavStringEx(
                $navComponentObject,
                "",
                "forum",
                true,
                $this,
                array(
                    "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N"
                )
            );
        }


    //    }

    //    $num = 10;
    //    $page = $_GET['page'];
    //    $posts = count($arResult["ITEMS"]);
    //    $total = intval(($posts - 1) / $num) + 1;
    //    $page = intval($page);
    //
    //    if(empty($page) or $page < 0) $page = 1;
    //        if($page > $total) $page = $total;
    //
    //    $start = $page * $num - $num;
    }
    $this->IncludeComponentTemplate();
```

есть index.php

```
    <?
    require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
    $APPLICATION->SetTitle("Partnerschaften");
    ?><?
    $GLOBALS['arrFilter_partners'] = array("!PROPERTY_ATTR_MEMBER_RUS"=>false);
    ?>


    <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
        "divier:partnerschaften", 
        ".default", 
        array(
            "CACHE_TIME" => "3600",
            "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
            "IBLOCK_ID" => array(
                0 => "2",
                1 => "3",
                2 => "15",
                3 => "16",
            ),
            "IBLOCK_TYPE_ID" => "content_germ",
            "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => ".default"
        ),
        false
    );?>


    <?//$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    //  "bitrix:news.list",
    //  "part_a",
    //  array(
    //      "DISPLAY_DATE" => "Y",
    //      "DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
    //      "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => "Y",
    //      "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => "Y",
    //      "AJAX_MODE" => "Y",
    //      "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "content_germ",
    //      "IBLOCK_ID" => array(
    //          0 => "2",
    //          1 => "3",
    //          2 => "15",
    //          3 => "16",
    //      ),
    //      "NEWS_COUNT" => "20",
    //      "SORT_BY1" => "ACTIVE_FROM",
    //      "SORT_ORDER1" => "DESC",
    //      "SORT_BY2" => "SORT",
    //      "SORT_ORDER2" => "ASC",
    //      "FILTER_NAME" => "",
    //      "FIELD_CODE" => array(
    //          0 => "",
    //          1 => "ATTR_MEMBER_RUS",
    //          2 => "ATTR_MEMBER_DE",
    //          3 => "ATTR_SHORT_TITLE",
    //          4 => "",
    //      ),
    //      "PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
    //          0 => "",
    //          1 => "ATTR_MEMBER_RUS",
    //          2 => "ATTR_MEMBER_DE",
    //          3 => "ATTR_SHORT_TITLE",
    //          4 => "",
    //      ),
    //      "CHECK_DATES" => "Y",
    //      "DETAIL_URL" => "",
    //      "PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => "",
    //      "ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
    //      "SET_TITLE" => "Y",
    //      "SET_BROWSER_TITLE" => "Y",
    //      "SET_META_KEYWORDS" => "Y",
    //      "SET_META_DESCRIPTION" => "Y",
    //      "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => "Y",
    //      "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => "Y",
    //      "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "Y",
    //      "HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL" => "Y",
    //      "PARENT_SECTION" => "",
    //      "PARENT_SECTION_CODE" => "",
    //      "INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS" => "Y",
    //      "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
    //      "CACHE_TIME" => "3600",
    //      "CACHE_FILTER" => "Y",
    //      "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
    //      "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "Y",
    //      "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
    //      "PAGER_TITLE" => "Новости",
    //      "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "Y",
    //      "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => "",
    //      "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "Y",
    //      "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
    //      "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "Y",
    //      "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => "Y",
    //      "SET_STATUS_404" => "Y",
    //      "SHOW_404" => "Y",
    //      "MESSAGE_404" => "",
    //      "PAGER_BASE_LINK" => "",
    //      "PAGER_PARAMS_NAME" => "arrPager",
    //      "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
    //      "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
    //      "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
    //      "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "",
    //      "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "part_a",
    //      "STRICT_SECTION_CHECK" => "N",
    //      "FILE_404" => ""
    //  ),
    //  false
    //);?>







    <?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>
```

и вывод в template.php

```
    <?
    if (!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED !== true) die();

    ?>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="events_header">
            <div>Veranstaltung</div>
            <div>Deutsche Partner</div>
            <div>Russische Partner</div>
        </div>
        <div class="events">
        <? foreach ($arResult["ITEMS"] as $item): ?>

    <?// print_r($item) ?>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="name"><a href="<?= $item["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"] ?>"><?= $item["PROPERTY_ATTR_SHORT_TITLE_VALUE"] ?></a></div>
                <div class="partners">
                    <div class="germany">
                        <? foreach ($item["PROPERTY_ATTR_MEMBER_DE_VALUE"] as $deMember): ?>
                            <div class="partner">
                                <a href="<?= $item["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"] ?>">
                                    <img src="<?= $deMember["DETAIL_PICTURE"] ?>" alt="<?= $item["PROPERTY_ATTR_SHORT_TITLE_VALUE"] ?>">
                                    <span>
                                        <?= $deMember["NAME"] ?>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        <? endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="russia">
                        <? foreach ($item["PROPERTY_ATTR_MEMBER_RUS_VALUE"] as $ruMember): ?>
                            <div class="partner">
                                <a href="<?= $item["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"] ?>">
                                    <img src="<?= $ruMember["DETAIL_PICTURE"] ?>" alt="<?= $item["PROPERTY_ATTR_SHORT_TITLE_VALUE"] ?>">
                                    <span>
                                        <?= $ruMember["NAME"] ?>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        <? endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <? endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?=$arResult["NAV_STRING"]?>
```

Comment: неужели никто не знает ответ?

Comment: тут CIBlockElement::GetList - что то не то вы прокидываете. Нужно разобраться с документацией https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getlist.php конкретно с фильтрацией по IBLOCK_ID, как минимум там написано если инфоблоки 2.0 то не будет работать если вы делаете выборку по свойствам. Ещё может быть ваши условия в логике не бирут просто данные из других инфоблоков (т.к. нет таких данных). Ну на крайний случай можно сделать 4 гет листа для каждого из инфоблоков

Comment: "ACTIVITY" - тут опечатка, такого нет, есть ACTIVE. В вопросе говорится про разделы, но вы наверно имеете ввиду вывод данных из 4 инфоблоков?

Comment: Да. 4 инфоблока. ACTIVITY - исправил, но ничего не решилось. Если ставить по одному айдишнику, то новости выводятся из каждого инфоблока. но если прописано вот так"IBLOCK_ID" => array(2,3,15,16), то выводятся только из какогото одного айдишника... а надо чтоб выводилось из всех сразу

Comment: мне еще подсказали что можно сделать цикл запросы для каждого айдишника - но я понятия не имею как это сделать. я пхп вообще плохо знаю

Comment: "цикл запросы для каждого айдишника" - возможно имели ввиду так, в файле component.php foreach($arParams['IBLOCK_ID'] as $key => $val ) { ...($arParams['IBLOCK_ID'] - тут находятся id переданные в компонент ) тут делаете тоже самое что ваш код после подключения модуля iblock только для гет листа указываете конкретный id $arFilter = array( "IBLOCK_ID" => $val ... после чего в вашем $arResult["ITEMS"] будут элементы из всех 4 инфоблоков. Либо надо разобраться почему из всех не берутся, для этого надо смотреть документацию, возможно просто нужно не передавать массив $arSelect в гетлист.

Comment: а можете написать готовый код страницы component.php ? оч прошу.. не очень понимаю куда что прописывать...

Comment: надо вам разбираться самому. Если что то не понимаете то и спрашивать это (например как передаются параметры в компонент или как писать циклы в php), если не найдёте в документациях ответа. (выше по сути уже написал,  если совсем грубо, 2рой строчкой добавьте foreach($arParams['IBLOCK_ID'] as $key => $val ) { , потом $arFilter = array( "IBLOCK_ID" => $val ..., а предпоследней строчкой }  ) . + у вас в шаблоне указано <?=$arResult["NAV_STRING"]?> постраничная навигация работать не будет скорее всего.

Answer (score 0):

@ssv32 так получается? вроде работает. Но как теперь сделать навигацию

```
<?php if (!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED !== true) die();

foreach($arParams['IBLOCK_ID'] as $key => $val ){



if (CModule::IncludeModule("iblock")) {
    $arSelect = array(
        "ID",
        "IBLOCK_ID",
        "PROPERTY_ATTR_SHORT_TITLE",
        "PROPERTY_ATTR_MEMBER_RUS",
        "PROPERTY_ATTR_MEMBER_DE",
        "DETAIL_PAGE_URL"
    );

    $arFilter = array(
        "IBLOCK_ID" => $val,
        "ACTIVE" => "Y",
        "!PROPERTY_ATTR_SHORT_TITLE" => false,
        array(
            "LOGIC" => "OR",
            array("!PROPERTY_ATTR_MEMBER_RUS" => false),
            array("!PROPERTY_ATTR_MEMBER_DE" => false)
        )
    );

    $arOrder = array(
        "PROPERTY_ATTR_SHORT_TITLE" => "ASC",
    );

    $res = CIBlockElement::GetList($arOrder, $arFilter, false, array("nPageSize" => 10, "bShowAll" => false), $arSelect);

    while ($ob = $res->GetNextElement()) {
        $arFields = $ob->GetFields();

//        if (!empty($arFields["PROPERTY_ATTR_MEMBER_RUS_VALUE"]) || (!empty($arFields["PROPERTY_ATTR_MEMBER_DE_VALUE"]))) {

        // Формируем массив немецких партнеров
        foreach ($arFields["PROPERTY_ATTR_MEMBER_DE_VALUE"] as &$deMember) {
            $deMemberRes = CIBlockElement::GetByID($deMember);
            while ($de = $deMemberRes->GetNextElement())
                $deMember = $de->GetFields();

            $deMember["DETAIL_PICTURE"] = CFile::GetPath($deMember["DETAIL_PICTURE"]);
        }

        // Формируем массив российских партнеров
        foreach ($arFields["PROPERTY_ATTR_MEMBER_RUS_VALUE"] as &$deMember) {
            $deMemberRes = CIBlockElement::GetByID($deMember);
            while ($de = $deMemberRes->GetNextElement())
                $deMember = $de->GetFields();

            $deMember["DETAIL_PICTURE"] = CFile::GetPath($deMember["DETAIL_PICTURE"]);
        }

        $arResult["ITEMS"][] = $arFields;

        $arResult["NAV_STRING"] = $res->GetPageNavStringEx(
            $navComponentObject,
            "",
            "forum",
            true,
            $this,
            array(
                "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N"
            )
        );
    }


//    }

//    $num = 10;
//    $page = $_GET['page'];
//    $posts = count($arResult["ITEMS"]);
//    $total = intval(($posts - 1) / $num) + 1;
//    $page = intval($page);
//
//    if(empty($page) or $page < 0) $page = 1;
//        if($page > $total) $page = $total;
//
//    $start = $page * $num - $num;
}

}
$this->IncludeComponentTemplate();
```

Comment: подключение модуля CModule::IncludeModule("iblock") можно вынести до цикла, что бы 4 раза не проверялось одно и тоже.

Comment: При текущем подходе постраничную навигацию будет сделать не просто. А тот кусок кода что у вас есть будет возвращать постраничную навигацию для последнего инфоблока.(думаю прокатило бы, если до цикла определить в каком инфоблоке будет наибольшее количество страниц и от этого инфоблока брать пагинацию. Но нужно сделать так что бы при выборе данных из инфоблока где указана страница на которой не должно быть данных этого инфоблока, не брались данные зациклено (что то передавать надо, в документации будет) + нужно в гет лист компонента прокидывать номер текущей страницы из ссылки(гет параметр)).

Comment: Может вам проще всегда все данные брать что бы пагинацию вообще не выводить?

Comment: а как выводить сразу все данные?

Comment: вообще тут много чего нужно.. и сортировка нужна. я вообще 1 раз такое делаю.ничего не понимаю

Comment: $res = CIBlockElement::GetList($arOrder, $arFilter, false, array("nPageSize" => 10, "bShowAll" => false), $arSelect);

Comment: типо здесь значение *10* изменить...?

Comment: да, почитайте док. и попробуйте менять эти параметры array("nPageSize" => 10, "bShowAll" => false), (если много сортировок и по всем 4 инфоблокам, лучше вернуться в начало и разобраться почему не выбираются данные сразу из 4х инфоблоков, т.к. вручную совмещать с учётом сортировки данные из 4 инфоблоков проблиматично будет)